# Pytorch lightning resuming from checkpoint with new data

Tags: pytorch-lightning

I'm wanting to continue the training process for a model using new data.

I understand that you can continue training a Pytorch Lightning model e.g.

`pl.Trainer(max_epochs=10, resume_from_checkpoint='./checkpoints/blahblah.ckpt')` for example, if you last checkpoint is saved at epoch 5. But is there a way to continue training by adding different data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, when you resume from a checkpoint you can provide the new `DataLoader` or `DataModule` during the training and your training will resume from the last epoch with the new data.

```py
trainer = pl.Trainer(max_epochs=10, resume_from_checkpoint='./checkpoints/blahblah.ckpt')

trainer.fit(model, new_train_dataloader)
```

Comment: if the model has been trained for 10 epochs previously and if I want to train for 5 more epoch should I keep `max_epochs=5` or `max_epochs=10`?
Reference: https://lightning.ai/forums/t/how-to-resume-training/432/8

Comment: How on earth can the `DataModule` during training be provided if we just load the model?

Answer (score 9):

To new users of Torch lightning, the new syntax looks something like this

`trainer = pl.Trainer()`
`trainer.fit(model,data,ckpt_path = "./path/to/checkpoint")`

Also since I don't have enough reputation to comment, if you have already trained for 10 epoch and you want to train for 5 more epoch, add the following parameters to the `Trainer`

`trainer = pl.Trainer(max_epochs = 15)`